# Is there some way to tell the compiler that certain function's return value won't change?

Tags: c++, compiler-optimization, lto

I use library libA, which in turn uses library libB. Now, libB has a thread-local index for the "current macguffin". Other threads (unless they start writing to arbitrary places in memory) cannot change the current thread's "current macguffin". Now, libA can't know you don't change the current macguffin between calls to its functions, so when you compile a libA function you get something like:

```
 callq  123 <libB::get_current_macguffin()+0x12>
 # other stuff here
```

in the object file. If you make many `libA` calls and don't change the current macguffin - you end up making many `libB::get_current_macguffin()` calls, which you shouldn't have to.

Now, is there a way to tell the compiler (or a linker doing LTO) that:

1. A certain function is pure / there are no side-effects which need to be reproduced by calling it.
2. The return value of consecutive calls to a pure function (possibly with restrictions on its parameter types),  with the same arguments, cannot return different values unless one of a set of other functions were called in between? (In our case, `libB::set_current_macguffin(macguffin_t new_macguffin)`)

... in a way which would make it drop the subsequent calls and cache the results?

Note:

- `libA` and `libB` are already compiled, I can't re-compile them. But - some of libA's code may be inline functions in a header; or the compiler itself may be duplicating libA code to avoid calls.
- I marked this question "C++", although it's valid for about any compiled language, really.

Comment: There are compiler-speficic ways, like __attribute__((pure))

Comment: You cannot recompile libA, but you expect the optimization to happen for libA code? I somehow don't get it...

Comment: The only thing that comes into my mind is to patch/wrap that function. And replace it with your own one that forwards the call to the original one. And do that in a way that the compiler can do that optimization. But iirc the `wrap` options that e.g. gcc  provides is not available on all platforms.

Comment: @dyp: 1. Some of libA's code may be inline functions in a header. 2. The compiler itself may be inlining libA code